# why we use xerces.jar in xml serialization?

Tags: java, xml

I have migrated my project from WebSphere 7 server, JDK 1.6 to Apache Tomcat 8, JDK 8. I get an error, when I export any product as XML. When I include **xerces.jar** the problem is solved. Why do we need it?

This is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate serializer
org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer
```

Comment: Because that's the XML library that your application has been coded to use, and that's where the library is loaded from!

Comment: I fixed some grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Look at the stack trace and share the code for the first method you see that's inside your own (not apache) code.

Comment: Actually the scene is that earliar i used (Rational software architecture, jdk 1.6 and tomcat 6) for project development but now i am moving to (eclipse, jdk 1.8, tomcat) everything is working fine but only one problem is occurring which i have specified. So why we need this jar xerces.jar? because this jar file creating a problem which is related to IDResolver.class